# Ethash vs Equihash in terms of memory hardness?

Tags: mining, hash-algorithm, ethash, asic-resistant

Ethereum's Ethash was designed to be memory hard with the intention of making the mining process ASIC-resistant. Zcash's [Equihash](https://www.internetsociety.org/sites/default/files/blogs-media/equihash-asymmetric-proof-of-work-based-generalized-birthday-problem.pdf) algorithm also promises the same. How do these two PoW systems compare to each other?

---

*Note*: I'm not looking for a detailed explanation or differences in implementations etc. I just want to know how these algorithms effect miners and end-users. For example, in some video, I remember Vitalik saying that Ethash is 200 times more memory hard that Scrypt (used by Litecoin). I'm looking for similar comparisons between Ethash and Equihash.

Comment: Not sure what the downvote was for. (Could be that the question is quite broad?) I'm interested in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Ethash vs Equihash memory hardness isn't a constant - it changes with time - but I'll try to provide a (very basic and generalised) method that you could use to work out what it is at any point in time.

Ethereum uses a generated DAG file which increases in size every 30,000 blocks (called an epoch). As of writing the current Ethereum epoch is #151 and the DAG size is 2.18 GB. You can find the current Ethash DAG details here: https://investoon.com/tools/dag_size

Equihash's memory hardness is dependent on the parameters used in its algorithm (based on Blake2b hashing) called n and k. According to the protocol paper (https://github.com/zcash/zips/blob/master/protocol/protocol.pdf), on the production Zcash network n=200 and k=9. That translates to ~500Mb memory requirement based on the algorithm implementations as defined by the authors of this article: https://www.cryptolux.org/index.php/Equihash. (Personally, I've found that the actual memory requirements when mining zCash tend to be a bit higher with a peak usage in the 800Mb-1.2Gb range.)

**So to give a simple answer to your question - one could say that Ethash is at least 2-4 times more memory hard than Equihash** (with that number set to grow as the Ethereum DAG epochs increase).

However there are more important nuances that you would need to factor in when assessing the two algorithms - especially for mining profitability -  most of which are outlined here: http://www.openwall.com/articles/Zcash-Equihash-Analysis